# List of all Team

Tags: spring, list, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to display a list of all existing Team, but on the screen I see only the last Team that I added.

Team that were created earlier and are in the repository are not shown.

teamList.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Team List</h1>
<br/><br/>
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Team Name</th>
            <th>Team Url</th>

        </tr>
        <tr th:each ="tm : ${teamForm}">
            <td th:utext="${tm.name}">...</td>
            <td th:utext="${tm.url}">...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">Back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

TeamForm

```
public class TeamForm {
    private String name;
    private String url; 
    public TeamForm() {
    }

    public TeamForm(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }
      getts und setts
}
```

AdminController

I use rest to redirect pages

maybe he does not take all the data from the repository?

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    TeamRepository teamRepository;


    @GetMapping("/admin/team/all")
    List<Team> allTeams() {
        return teamRepository.findAll();
    }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String addTeam(Model model, @ModelAttribute("teamForm") @Validated TeamForm teamForm,
            BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        System.out.println("addTeam invoked");
        Team newTeam = new Team();
        newTeam.setName(teamForm.getName());
        newTeam.setUrl(teamForm.getUrl());
        teamRepository.save(newTeam);
        return "teamList";
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String teamList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("teamForm", allTeams());
        return "teamList";
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminPage(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("teamForm",new TeamForm());
        model.addAttribute("eventForm",new EventForm());
        return "admin";
    }
```

Comment: Which page are you requesting?  `/admin` or `/admin/team`?

Comment: I want to be displayed here /admin/team